# Collect input from a form in second page without losing input from form in first page

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

i'm trying to let a user enter a certain item code, which then takes them to a page where they can see the code and the item information from the database based on what code they entered. On this second page, I want the user to be able to enter another item code (under the table) with another submit button which will update the table with the other item they added which gets it from the database. How do i do this without losing the previous data on the table?

Code so far:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Scanned Items</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <h1 align="center"><u><font color="blue">List of Scanned Items</font></u></h1>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th> Item Code </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Taxable </th>
            <th> Tax </th>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> ${productcatalogue.code}</td>
                    <td> ${productcatalogue.name}</td>
                    <td> $${productcatalogue.price}</td>
                    <td> ${productcatalogue.taxable}</td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    DBConnection dbConn = (DBConnection)request.getServletContext()
        .getAttribute("dbConn");

    ProductCatalogueDAO productcatalogueDAO = new ProductCatalogueDAO();
    String itemcode = request.getParameter("itemcode");
    ProductCatalogue productcatalogue = productcatalogueDAO.getItems(dbConn.getConnection(), itemcode);
    request.setAttribute("productcatalogue", productcatalogue);

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher
    (response.encodeURL("scannedItems.jsp"));
    view.forward(request, response);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can give you overview to handle it, i just not used Database to
>   store it, but remaining things i did it.
>
> Just follow this sequence and you will get your solution,
>
> just create one jsp file, here in my case it's ***a1.jsp***

**------------------------ a1.jsp code ---------------------------------**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.stackoverflow.ItemBean"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Taxable</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        <%
        ArrayList<ItemBean> list = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
           if(session.getAttribute("allitems") != null){
               list =  (ArrayList<ItemBean>)session.getAttribute("allitems");   
           }

            for(ItemBean ib : list){
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= ib.getItemCode() %></td>
                    <td><%= ib.getItemname() %></td>
                    <td><%= ib.getPrice() %></td>
                    <td><%= ib.getTaxable() %></td>
                    <td><%= ib.getTax() %></td>
                    <td><i>Saved</i></td>
                </tr>   

                <%}%>

        <form action="ItemSubmit.do" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="itemCode" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="itemname" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" /></td>
            <td><select name="taxable">
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tax" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

**--------------- ItemSubmit.java servlet code -----------------**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ArrayList<ItemBean> listBean = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();

        String itemCode = request.getParameter("itemCode");
        String itemname = request.getParameter("itemname");
        double price = 0;
        String taxable = request.getParameter("taxable");
        double tax = 0;
        String remark = "saved";

        try {
            price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price")) ;
            tax =   Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tax"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            remark = e.getMessage();
        }

        if(session.getAttribute("allitems") != null){
            listBean = (ArrayList<ItemBean>)session.getAttribute("allitems");
        }

        ItemBean itemBean = new ItemBean(itemCode, itemname, price, taxable, tax,remark);
        //save itemBean to DB-if needed then...
        listBean.add(itemBean);
        session.setAttribute("allitems",listBean);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/a1.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

**-------------------- ItemBean.java plain java class ---------------**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class ItemBean {
        String itemCode;
        String itemname;
        double price;
        String taxable;
        double tax;
        String remark;

        public ItemBean(String itemCode, String itemname, double price, String taxable,double tax , String remark ) {
            this.itemCode = itemCode;
            this.itemname = itemname;
            this.price = price;
            this.taxable = taxable;
            this.tax  = tax;
            this.remark = remark;
        }


        public String getItemCode() {
            return itemCode;
        }
        public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
            this.itemCode = itemCode;
        }
        public String getItemname() {
            return itemname;
        }
        public void setItemname(String itemname) {
            this.itemname = itemname;
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String getTaxable() {
            return taxable;
        }
        public void setTaxable(String taxable) {
            this.taxable = taxable;
        }
        public double getTax() {
            return tax;
        }
        public void setTax(double tax) {
            this.tax = tax;
        }

        public String getRemark() {
            return remark;
        }

        public void setRemark(String remark) {
            this.remark = remark;
        }

}
```

**--------------- OUT-PUT --------------------**

[image]